# Python AzureOperationPoller occasionally fails

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I have a simple Python application that uses `AzureOperationPoller.wait()` to wait for ResouceGroup deletion and Deployment completion. Occasionally wait() throwing an error:

> RuntimeError: No recommended backend was available. Install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See README.rst for details.

Has anyone seen this before? One thing I'm worried about is that the application is multi-threaded and there might be several threads all sitting on the wait() so I'm sure the SDK is continually polling Azure for status.

Is it the threading that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I never saw that at all (I own this code at MS). Keyring is used by the authentication system to refresh the authentication token when it got expired. So my guess is that your token expired before the end of the Long Running Operation (LRO), and AzureOperationPoller got issue to refresh the token. What kind of issue exactly, I'm not sure yet.

Could you open an issue in the tracker, specifying your system (very important, keyring installs completely different backend depending on the system), python version, a "pip freeze" (or least version of msrestazure and keyring):
https://github.com/Azure/msrestazure-for-python

Please link this question, so I made the connection.

Thanks!